# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1 address=0x2f9cd928) when running project on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

on the simulator everything worked fine but on my ipod touch 6.1.5 i am getting error when clicking on any button in the alert view.

```
-(void)optionsButtonPressed {
    UIAlertView *optionsAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options"       message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add Note",@"Recover Last Note",@"Recover All", nil];
    [optionsAlertView show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Add Note"]) {
        AddNoteViewController *addNoteViewController = [[AddNoteViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

i wont post the whole method because its long.... the problem is that when the alertview appears, and as soon as i press on any button it is crashing which was not happening in the simulator.

i am using xcode 4.6.3

here is the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1 address=0x2f9cd928)

NOTE: in the first viewController(first to load), i have an alert view that is working just fine, and has a method to handle which button is pressed.

Comment: Look at the stack trace. Where does the crash happen? Is your delegate method called or does it not get that far?

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint to find the line where the crash happens?

Comment: Side note - do not compare button labels. It's error prone (you might change the label or you might support other languages some day). Just check the index.

Comment: the crash is happening on the line: -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

Comment: the delegate method is called

Comment: @user3188822 The problem is either that the object that is the `delegate` to the `UIAlertView` has been deallocated or there is some problem inside the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method itself. What does the `self` refer to in the instantiation of the `UIAlertView` object? The view controller? Or something else? By the way, if you enable zombies, it will confirm whether the problem is that the object in question has been deallocated (which is almost certainly the case).

Comment: try 'Enable Zombie Objects' in Scheme and see the result.